# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.DaftarTugas

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I already tried many solving code in the stack overflow but its still error yet. Please help me

firebase database structure :
[image: here database]

This is tugas firebase structure, its doing well. But still dont have name from its parent. So i want to add them
[image]

error code:

> E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:
>   Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type
>   com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.DaftarTugas
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zza(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.TwoFragment$1.onDataChange(TwoFragment.java:90)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
>                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
>                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
>                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5555)
>                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)

DaftarTugas.java

```
package com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp;

    /**
     * Created by Yehezkiel on 7/12/2018.
     */

    public class DaftarTugas{
        private String judul_tugas;
        private String deskripsi_tugas;
        private String tanggal_kumpul;
        private String tanggal_tugas;
        private String nama_matkul;


        public DaftarTugas(String nama_matkul,String judul_tugas, String deskripsi_tugas, String tanggal_kumpul, String tanggal_tugas) {
            this.nama_matkul = nama_matkul;
            this.judul_tugas = judul_tugas;
            this.deskripsi_tugas = deskripsi_tugas;
            this.tanggal_kumpul = tanggal_kumpul;
            this.tanggal_tugas = tanggal_tugas;
        }

        public DaftarTugas() {

        }


        public String getNama_matkul() {
            return nama_matkul;
        }

        public void setNama_matkul(String nama_matkul) {
            this.nama_matkul = nama_matkul;
        }


        public String getJudul_tugas() {
            return judul_tugas;
        }

        public void setJudul_tugas(String judul_tugas) {
            this.judul_tugas = judul_tugas;
        }

        public String getDeskripsi_tugas() {
            return deskripsi_tugas;
        }

        public void setDeskripsi_tugas(String deskripsi_tugas) {
            this.deskripsi_tugas = deskripsi_tugas;
        }

        public String getTanggal_kumpul() {
            return tanggal_kumpul;
        }

        public void setTanggal_kumpul(String tanggal_kumpul) {
            this.tanggal_kumpul = tanggal_kumpul;
        }

        public String getTanggal_tugas() {

            return tanggal_tugas;
        }

        public void setTanggal_tugas(String tanggal_tugas) {

            this.tanggal_tugas = tanggal_tugas;
        }
    }
```

my TwoFragment :

```
 for(int i = 0;i<obj2.size();i++){
            mataKuliahRef.child(obj2.get(i)).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override

                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
                    tugas = dataSnapshot1.getValue(DaftarTugas.class);
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            mataKuliahRef.child(obj2.get(i)).child("tugas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    listTugas.clear();
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot dataHasil : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            final String idTugas = dataHasil.getKey();

                            Log.e("Yhz2", idTugas);

                            daftarTugasRef.child(idTugas).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2) {
                                    tugas = dataSnapshot2.getValue(DaftarTugas.class);
                                    listTugas.add(tugas);
                                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        }

                }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

I want to add 2 difference value to 1 adapter, this one got error when i add value from child.("name"). The main problem is here I think :

```
mataKuliahRef.child(obj2.get(i)).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1) {
        tugas = dataSnapshot1.getValue(DaftarTugas.class);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: @AlexMamo done sir

Comment: So basically what are you looking for? You want to have a list of `DaftarTugas` objects? Or you want a list of string property like `name` or `day`?

Comment: I just want to add name to the DaftarTugas, daftar tugas have name, deskripsi_tugas,judul_tugas,tanggal_kumpul,tanggal_tugas. There are deskripsi_tugas,judul_tugas,tanggal_kumpul,tanggal_tugas already doing well. So i want to add 1 more to that java class which is name from another database

Comment: the main problem is the recycler view is doing well to populate data from tugas. But i want add 1 more child from its parrent which is name to the RecyclerView

Comment: Have you tried to add that `name` as a property of your `DaftarTugas`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Sure, i hv been update the code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

the error message reads `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.yehezkiel.eclassapp.DaftarTugas` ...which might be the result of trying to parse `.child("name")` (which probably would return nothing but a `String`) into class `DaftarTugas`.

one can instance without parsing (difficult to tell while not knowing what is actually being returned):

```
DaftarTugas item = new DaftarTugas();
item.setName(tugas);
tugas.add(item);
```

or add one constructor, which accepts only the name.

Comment: that code itsnt encountered a problem. It doing well,and can apear in my recycler view. The problem is the one before that.

Comment: @YehezkielL updated the answer, hence I mistook to direction of the wrongful cast at first... and maybe check out https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/ once.

Comment: So what's the solution sir? I did log the datasnapshot1,and its gave me the correct result. But idk why it was not send to the daftartugas

Comment: you didnt give me the solution sir

Comment: @YehezkielL there's nothing to add.